# how to create multidimensional array getter in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, getter

My problem is that I want to create a getter which uses multidimensional array. I also use php version lower than 5.4 so I can't use array dereferencing.

```
class someClass{ 
protected someArray; // array( 'key1' => array( 'key2' => 'val'))

 function __construct(){ 
  // calling
  $this -> getVar( array( 'key1' , 'key2' ) ); 
 }

 public function getVar( $keys ){ 
  // return someArray multidimensional values 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Please post some examples, it's not very clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
class someClass{ 
  protected someArray; 

  function __construct(){ 
    $this->someArray = array(
                        'key1' => array('name' => 'Akhil', 'loc' => 'india'),
                        'key2' => array('name' => 'Akash', 'loc' => 'usa'),
                        'key3' => array('name' => 'Dad', 'loc' => 'dubai'),
                        'key4' => array('name' => 'Mom', 'loc' => 'uae')
    );

    // calling
    print_r( $this -> getVar( array( 'key1' , 'key2' ) ) ); 
  }

  public function getVar( $keys ){ 
    // return someArray multidimensional values 

    $temp = array();
    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
      $temp[] = $this->someArray[ $key ];
    }

    return $temp;

  } 
}
```

**EDIT**

As per the comment you provided below in my answer, here's how you could do that:

```
  public function getVar( $main_key, $sub_key ){ 
    // return someArray multidimensional values       

    return $this->someArray[ $main_key ][ $sub_key ];

  }
```

Comment: I want to get specific multidimensional value. Lets say I want to get someArray[ 'key1' ][ 'name' ] and call it like getVar( 'key1' , 'name' )